# VBA to assign nested if condition to some range cells

Tags: excel, vba

i need a requirement of VBA code to assign the below formula to range G4:G1000,

by comparing other columns and current date, please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: =IF(A4="Ended OK","Completed",IF(A4="Executing","In progress",IF(D4=1,ROUND(((NOW()-1)-(B4+E4))*24,0),ROUND(((NOW())-(B4+E4))*24,0))))

Comment: Which aspect of your code are you having trouble with? Please show your work in progress, and point out any errors you are getting.

Comment: @Rana...record a macro

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, you may need to modify wb and ws to your needs.

```
Sub mysub()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb As ActiveWorkbook
Set ws As wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("G4:G1000").Formula = "=IF(A4="Ended OK","Completed",IF(A4="Executing","In progress",IF(D4=1,ROUND(((NOW()-1)-(B4+E4))*24,0),ROUND(((NO‌​W())-(B4+E4))*24,0))‌​))"
End Sub
```